# Spring Security - Login not working when enabling HTTPS

Tags: java, spring-mvc, ssl, spring-security

Newbie to Spring security. I had gone through some tutorials and implemented Spring Security. I have few pages which I secured via login.

Here is my **spring-security.xml** file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

    <security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/person*/*"
            access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    </security:http>

    <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider>
            <security:user-service>
                <security:user name="admin" password="password"
                    authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />
            </security:user-service>
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

</beans>
```

From my index.jsp, when I try to access `persons` URL, it's asking for authentication. And I have logout URL. Inside `persons` JSP page.

```
<a href="<c:url value="logout" />" > Logout</a>
```

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/logout", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView logoutPage(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (auth != null) {
            new SecurityContextLogoutHandler().logout(request, response, auth);
        }
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/");
    }
```

It's working fine. Except few things. - When I try to go to `/person/add`, it's directly going to the page instead of asking the Authentication. Why? and how to resolve? Do I need to mention all URLs in intercept URLs (What if I have many?)

Well the main thing is, I'm trying to configure SSL as well for my application.

I installed [this tutorial](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/12/securing-your-tomcat-app-with-ssl-and-spring-security.html).

1. I have created ketstore
2. Configured in tomcat, server.xml
3. Configured in web.xml

   Now I have the following in spring-security.xml

   `<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
               <security:intercept-url pattern="/**"
                   requires-channel="https" />
               <security:intercept-url pattern="/person*/*"
                   access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
           </security:http>`

The SSL is working. But Login is not working. When I go to `persons` URL, it's showing the page without asking for authentication. Why?

I tried adding `access=hasRole('ROLE_USER')`, then tomcat is showing Access denied when I give correct credentials.

How to solve it? I want to enable SSL for all URLs.

I'm using Spring 4.2.2.RELEASE and Spring Security 4.0.2.RELEASE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, try to rewrite your `security:intercept-url` as following:

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/person*" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
<security:intercept-url pattern="/person/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"
```

Regarding SSL, the tutorial is very nice and it should work out of the box, maybe the problem is again with intercepting url's, try my suggestion.

Comment: Yeah, I tried this and is working. And SSL too. Just in Web.xml is fine. Or for each intercept url we need to mention the requires-channel